# How to add a header and/or footer to a sed or awk stream?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, regular-expression

I have a bunch of output going through sed and awk.

How can I prefix the output with START and suffix the answer with END?

For example, if I have

```
All this code
on all these lines
and all these
```

How could I get:

```
START
All this code
on all these lines
and all these
END
```

?

My attempt was:

```
awk '{print "START";print;print "END"}'
```

but I got

```
...
START
    All this code
END
START
    on all these lines
END
START
    and all these
END
```

Comment: [Using BEGIN and END](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html)...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This works, as indicated by [jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226206/how-to-add-a-header-or-footer-to-a-sed-or-awk-stream#comment384461_226206):

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "START"}; {print}; END{print "END"}'
```

Answer (score 13):

This can be done in `sed` with

```
sed -e $'1i\\\nSTART' -e $'$a\\\nEND'
```

`1i` means **i**nsert before line 1;
`$a` means **a**ppend after the last line. 
The `$'…'` syntax is bash-specific. 
In other shells, you should be able to do this with:

```
sed -e '1i\Enter
START' -e '$a\Enter
END'Enter
```

Warning: the question says “I have a bunch of output ...” 
If you run the above command with no data, you will get no output,
because the command depends on there actually *being*
a first line and a last line. 
The other two answers will give the header and footer
even if the input is null.

Answer (score 11):

If you're already using sed, you can use `1` to match the first line and `$` to match the last line (see [Scott's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226225)). If you're already using awk, you can use a `BEGIN` block to run code before the first line and an `END` block to run code after the last line (see [Michael Durrant's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226208)).

If all you need to do is add a header and a footer, just use `echo` and `cat`.

```
echo START
cat
echo END
```

In a pipeline, to run multiple commands, use `{ … }` to tell the parser that they're one single compound command.

```
content-generator |
{ echo START; cat; echo END; } |
postprocessor
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '1s/.*/START\n&/g' -e '$s/.*/&\nEND/g' filename

START
All this code
on all these lines
and all these
END
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('filename','r')
o=k.readlines()
for i in range(0,len(o),1):
    if ( i == 0 ):
        print "START"
        print o[i].strip()
    elif ( i == (len(o)-1)):
        print o[i].strip()
        print "END"
    else:
        print o[i].strip()
```

output

```
START
All this code
on all these lines
and all these
END
```