# How to add header and trailer to the existing file straight away

Tags: text-processing, awk

Is there a simple way to add in header & trailer to an existing text file? Same directory same text file. For example the `awk` ?
Appreciate some help on the explanation on how to process it with `awk`. Thanks.

Cause what I do know consist quite some steps. Please refer to below:

Suppose I wanted to add header to trailer to an existing file **ALERT.txt**
The file is in the directory called `$Source_Dir`

The text file contains column name, so I have two variable `Record_Count` & `Actual_Record_Count` to count the record:

```
Record_Count=`wc -l < ${Source_Dir}/${Output_File_Name} | tr -d " "`
Actual_Record_Count=`expr ${Record_Count} - 1`
```

First, I create a text file called `ALERT` with the header to `$Target_Dir`

```
echo ${Bus_date} >${Target_Dir}/${Output_File_Name}
```

Then, I add in the `Alert.txt` from `$Source_Dir` to the new file created in `$Target_Dir`

```
cat ${Source_Dir}/${Output_File_Name} >> ${Target_Dir}/${Output_File_Name}
```

Lastly, I continue adding in the trailer to the file `Alert.txt` in `$Target_Dir`.
The trailer will contains the record count

```
echo "EOF${Actual_Record_Count}" >>${Target_Dir}/${Output_File_Name}
```

Comment: `printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n' "HEADER" "$(<alert.txt)" "FOOTER" >alert.txt.tmp && mv alert.txt.tmp alert.txt` ?

Comment: Yup, thanks a lot. I shouldn't make things complicated.

Comment: `{ echo "HEADER"; cat alert.txt; echo "FOOTER"; } > tmp && mv tmp alert.txt`

Comment: `perl -i -0777pe 's/.*/HEADER\n$&FOOTER\n/s' alert.txt`

Comment: Your instinct to use `awk` seems good to me: you can probably avoid the `wc -l` and simply use awk's record count `NR` in an `END` block e.g. `awk -v bus_date="${BUS_DATE}" 'BEGIN{print bus_date} {print} END{printf "EOF%d\n", NR}' file`. If `BUS_DATE` really is just a datestamp, you may be able to generate that internally as well (at least with GNU awk).

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, with `NR` I don't have to specify `Record_Count` anymore, it help to simplify the code.

Comment: I’d probably use [ed(1)](http://www.mirbsd.org/man1/ed) to avoid the temporary file but @RakeshSharma’s solution is decent too (heemay!’s has massive overhead for larger files).

Comment: see also [How to add a header and/or footer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226206)

Answer (score 0):

So, you have some shell variable, `$Bus_date` that you want to add on a line by itself as the header.  Then there should follow the contents of `$Source_Dir/$Output_File_Name`, followed by the string `EOFNN` where `NN` is the number of lines in that file minus one.

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v head="$Bus_date" 'BEGIN { print head } { print } END { print "EOF" NR-1 }' "$Source_Dir/$Output_File_Name" >"$Target_Dir/$Output_File_Name"
```

The script is:

```
BEGIN { print head }
      { print }
END   { print "EOF" NR-1 }
```

On the command line, we set the `awk` variable `head` to the value of `$Bus_date`.  This value is outputted before we start reading from the given file, by the `BEGIN` block.

The `{ print }` block ensures that the given file is passed through as is, without modification.

The `END` block uses the built-in variable `NR` which holds the number of records (lines) read so far. In the `END` block, `NR` will be the number of lines in the file that was read.